# Cartesian Coordinate Formatting with TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

Using TikZ, I would like to create a coordinate plane which describes the rectangular coordinates (x,y). However, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Here is an example of something I am trying to do:

[image: coords]

However, I only want one point, and keep the x and y axes graphed. Also, I would like to have variable representing the coordinate, like (x,y) written instead of (2,3). Finally, I would like (0,x) and (x,0) to be written where the points would be, but without the points actually graphed.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Posting the code for the image would be a good start - or whatever you have towards it. So where the x axis has the mark `2` you also want to have a label `(x,0)`? (Or did you really mean `(0,x)`? I was assuming a typo.) Won't that be rather confusing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-eucl}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[](-3,-3)(6,6)
    \psaxes{->}(0,0)(-3,-3)(5.5,5.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
    \psset{PointNameSep=18pt,PosAngle=45,linestyle=dashed}
    \pstGeonode[PointName=A{(3,3)},linecolor=red](3,3){A}
    \psCoordinates[linecolor=red,showpoints=false](A)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Next time, please provide at least some code for people to work with. Automation, simplification and modification are left as an exercise for the reader.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path [draw, help lines, opacity=.5]  (-11,-11) grid (11,11);
    \foreach \i in {1,...,10} \draw (\i,2.5pt) -- +(0,-5pt) node [anchor=north, font=\small] {$\i$} (-\i,2.5pt) -- +(0,-5pt) node [anchor=north, font=\small] {$-\i$} (2.5pt,\i) -- +(-5pt,0) node [anchor=east, font=\small] {$\i$} (2.5pt,-\i) -- +(-5pt,0) node [anchor=east, font=\small] {$-\i$};
    \draw [->] (-10,0) -- (10,0) node [anchor=south] {$x$};
    \draw [->] (0,-10) -- (0,10) node [anchor=west] {$y$};
    \path [draw=blue, ultra thick, text=blue, densely dashed] (0,6) node [anchor=south west] {$(0,y)$} -| (8,0) node [anchor=south west] {$(x,0)$} node [anchor=south west, midway] {$(x,y)$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Cartesian plane]

Answer (score 2):

Here is the exact reproduction of the picture using `tkz-euclide`.

```
\documentclass[border=3]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \tkzInit[xmin=-6,ymin=-6,xmax=6,ymax=6]
    \tkzAxeXY
    \tkzGrid
    \tkzDefPoints{0/3/A,
        2/3/B,
        2/0/C}
    \tkzDrawSegments[color=blue, ultra thick, densely dashed](A,B B,C)
    \tkzDrawPoints[size=10,color=red](A,B,C)
    \tkzLabelPoint[above right,color=blue](A){$(0,3)$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above right,color=blue](B){$(2,3)$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above right,color=blue](C){$(2,0)$}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/1/D,
        -3/1/E,
        -3/0/F}
    \tkzDrawSegments[color=red, ultra thick, densely dashed](D,E E,F)
    \tkzDrawPoints[size=10,color=red](D,E,F)
    \tkzLabelPoint[above left,color=blue](D){$(0,1)$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above left,color=blue](E){$(-3,1)$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above left,color=blue](F){$(-3,0)$}
    \tkzDefPoints{0/-2.5/G,
        -1.5/-2.5/H,
        -1.5/0/I}
    \tkzDrawSegments[color=red, ultra thick, densely dashed](G,H H,I)
    \tkzDrawPoints[size=10,color=red](G,H,I)
    \tkzLabelPoint[right,color=blue](G){$(0,-2.5)$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[below,color=blue](H){$(-1.5,-2.5)$}
    \tkzLabelPoint[above,color=blue](I){$(-1.5,0)$}

    \tkzLabelPoint[above right,color=blue]({0,0}){$(0,0)$}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since this is repetitive code, the number of lines can be reduced by two third. But I left it more verbose so that it is easy to follow.

Comment: Just an update, \usetkzobj{all} is not required for the time being.